# C# JSON Array get value by key without strongly typed class in for each loop

Tags: c#, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to fetch the values from the key/value pairs shown within the inner brackets inside the rows[]

The class I use to de-serialize the JSON object does not contain individual values given they may change between different data sets.

JSON Object looks like this:

```
{
  "columns": [
    "(Column 1)",
    "@Level",
    "@Exception",
    "@Properties"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "2020-09-09T19:04:54.8422073Z",
      "Information",
      null,
      {
        "LogEventCategory": "System",
        "LogEventType": "Application Startup",
        "LogEventSource": "",
        "LogUserId": "",
        "LogUsername": "",
        "LogForename": "",
        "LogSurname": "",
        "LogData": "Application Starting Up",
        "MachineName": "DESKTOP-OS52032",
        "ProcessId": 16608,
        "ThreadId": 1,
        "ApplicationSource": "WebApp-RAZOR"
      }
    ],
    [
      "2020-09-09T19:09:06.5560521Z",
      "Information",
      null,
      {
        "LogEventCategory": "System",
        "LogEventType": "Application Startup",
        "LogEventSource": "",
        "LogUserId": "",
        "LogUsername": "",
        "LogForename": "",
        "LogSurname": "",
        "LogData": "Application Starting Up",
        "MachineName": "DESKTOP-OS52032",
        "ProcessId": 15588,
        "ThreadId": 1,
        "ApplicationSource": "WebApp-RAZOR"
      }
    ],
  "statistics": {
    "scannedEventCount": 11,
    "matchingEventCount": 6,
    "uncachedSegmentsScanned": false,
    "elapsedMilliseconds": 0.1267
  }
}
```

The values I'm trying to fetch are the ones listed:

```
"LogEventCategory": "System",
"LogEventType": "Application Startup",
"LogEventSource": "",
"LogUserId": "",
"LogUsername": "",
"LogForename": "",
"LogSurname": "",
"LogData": "Application Starting Up",
"MachineName": "DESKTOP-OS52032",
"ProcessId": 16608,
"ThreadId": 1,
"ApplicationSource": "WebApp-RAZOR"
```

When looping through the JSON object, I want to retrieve the values using some form of LINQ query or similar.

So far I've only been able to retrieve the first level items:

```
foreach (var item in logs.Rows)
{
    Timestamp = DateTime.Parse(item.First().ToString()), // = "2020-09-09T19:04:54.8422073Z"
    Level = item.Skip(1).First().ToString(), // = "Information"
    Exception = (item.Skip(2).First() ?? "-").ToString(), // = "-" in this example becuase json value is null
}
```

Class for de-serializing the JSON:

```
public class QueryLogEvents
{
    [JsonProperty("columns")]
    public string[] Columns { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rows")]
    public object[][] Rows { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("statistics")]
    public Statistics Statistics { get; set; }
}

public class Statistics
{
    [JsonProperty("scannedEventCount")]
    public int ScannedEventCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("matchingEventCount")]
    public int MatchingEventCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("uncachedSegmentsScanned")]
    public bool UncachedSegmentsScanned { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("elapsedMilliseconds")]
    public float ElapsedMilliseconds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the JSON data format under your control? Mixing types in an array is not ideal.

Comment: Nope the JSON array is returned from SEQ Logger. The values I've highlighted that I want to retrieve, may have additional key/value pairs between different log transactions, if that makes sense...

Comment: You might try modeling `Rows` as List<dynamic> and casting elements as needed, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459064/json-net-parsing-mixed-string-and-array

Comment: The class I've shown in my question was created using "paste json as classes" in VS using the structure from the JSON, I just need to figure how to get values from the inner list of objects within the rows array. I don't understand the code in the suggested link you've shown.

Comment: What actual problem are you encountering? Is the 4th element not present? Your code doesn't show an attempt to access it.

Comment: I don't know what code is required to retrieve the subset of values from 4th element.

Comment: The `foreach` has comma's and not the expected semi-colons and the JSON is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Try `dynamic` it was designed but situations like this as an intended use case. If you're using newtonsoft it will just work

Answer (score 0):

OK, following some of the suggestions, through trial and error I got this to work using the dynamic JObject:

Note below 'result' is the JSON string returned from an API I was calling.

Please refer to the JSON structure shown in my original question to see how I got these properties:

```
dynamic jsonObject = JObject.Parse(result);
dynamic rows = jsonObject.rows;

foreach (var property in rows)
{   
   Console.WriteLine(property[0]); // = "2020-09-09T19:09:06.5560521Z"
   Console.WriteLine(property[1]); // = "Information"
   Console.WriteLine(property[2]); // = null
   Console.WriteLine(property[3]["LogEventCategory"]); // = "System"
   Console.WriteLine(property[3]["LogEventType"]); // = "Application Startup"
   Console.WriteLine(property[3]["LogEventSource"]);
   // And the rest of the properties required from the fourth object i.e. the items within the inner paranthesis.
   // Note in the foreach loop, we will iterate through 'rows' array
   // Instead of using console.writeline, in producton code i'll be adding ther items to a list.
}
```

Final Note: using the dynamic JObject parsing means we do no need any C# class at all now so the one shown in my question would be removed from my code.